# Is "Ha Ha Point" English or a makeup word from other language?

Tags: word-usage

I looked up the Yahoo Dictionary of Hong Kong,
and it tells me the word I was looking for is this: "Ha Ha Point".

Yahoo Dictionary says "Ha Ha Point" is a network language that means "punch line", which is usually the part of a joke that makes you laugh.

I get that "Ha Ha" mimics the sound of laughter and that a "point" to which you can't help but laugh is the result of the punch line, but is "Ha Ha Point" English? Is it really a network language claimed by Yahoo Dictionary? To me this "Ha Ha Point" is too strange to be valid.

Comment: What word were using using in your search?

Comment: I've never heard of this. Also, I try not to rely too much on Yahoo for educational purposes.

Comment: @Peter  : I was using Yahoo Dictionary to look for the English translation for the Chinese word '笑點' and Yahoo Dictionary said the answer is 'Ha Ha Point', but later on my further search with Google finds that the correct translation for that Chinese word is supposed to be 'punch line'. That is why I'm curious to know whether 'Ha Ha Point' is true English or just a makeup word. ( '笑' means 'laugh'  and  '點' means 'point'.)

Comment: @Adam Starrh : I agree. I don't think Yahoo is professional enough in terms of it dictionary especially when it comes to educational purpose or language learning.

Comment: Ha Ha Point is a made up word. It looks like Yahoo took 笑 = Ha Ha and 点 = point and stuck them together. Not sure why someone translated using "Ha Ha", should be laugh or smile.

Comment: Punchline would be the correct word.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard this phrase before, but it's clear enough. The **point** would be *the moment when* the laughter occurs, analogous to "the breaking point", the moment when something under tension finally snaps.

The underlying idea is that joke is happening *in linear time*.

We can say "At that *point* in my trip across the country, I was low on cash"
or "At that *point* in the story..."

**Point** can also mean "idea" or "purpose".

We can ask "What's your *point*?" and thereby mean "what idea are you trying to get across?"  or ask "What's the *point* of shining your shoes if you're going to walk in the mud?" and thereby mean "Why do that, if you're only going to undo it or ruin it right away?"